# Strange behavior in shell script variables

Tags: shell, variables

I writing a shell script to parse some file using `grep` and use the result in subsequent commands.

The relevant part of the source code is

```
VERSION=`grep "^Stable tag:" readme.md | awk -F' ' '{print $NF}'`
echo $VERSION
echo "Readme file version is $VERSION is it correct"
```

The relevant line in the readme.md file is

```
Stable tag: 2.2.2
```

You would expect a output of

```
2.2.2
Readme file version is 2.2.2 is it correct
```

But I am getting the following as the output

```
2.2.2
 is it correctrsion is 2.2.2
```

I am pretty sure there is no (non-printable or non-ascii) character at the end of line in my text file. I checked it by enabling the `:set invlist` command in vim.

Any idea why it is happening like this? Or any other ideas to debug this issue?

Comment: You can use awk alone without grep: `awk -F' ' '/^Stable tag:/{print $NF}' readme.md`

Comment: @aragaer Thanks. Didn't know that I can use `awk` this way. Now that I have to include `tr` also (see the answer below), do you think I can still do it using `awk` alone?

Comment: `man awk` and I see `sub` there. Probablly something like `awk -F' ' '/^Stable tag:/{sub("\r", "", $NF); print $NF}' readme.md`, though I'd think about sed at that point already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a DOS edited file and you working on a Unix like system. Strip the carriage return (Ctrl-M).

You could use `tr(1)` to remove those:

```
VERSION=`grep "^Stable tag:" readme.md | tr -d '\015' | awk -F' ' '{print $NF}'`
```

Awk probably also has some builtin feature to work on these but I do not know awk enough for this.

Comment: Any idea how I can remove it from the shell script variable?

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be the issue. Strange this character didn't appear when I enabled hidden characters in vim.

Comment: `tr -d '\r'` also works, and is possibly more understandable than an octal code.

Comment: Use `VERSION=$(sed '/Stable tag:/s/.* \(.*\)\r/\1/' readme.md)` instead of the grep|tr|awk pipeline

Comment: `VERSION=$(sed -n '/Stable tag:/s/.* \(.*\)\r/\1/p' readme.md)` as readme.md might contain other lines too.

Comment: @glennjackman & aragaer: these should be answers, not comments.